# Exclude files from beeing checked in NetBeans 7

Tags: java, netbeans, playframework

I'm using the [Play](http://www.playframework.org/) framework with NetBeans 7. Play uses template files with the ending `.html` although it is not pure html. NetBeans checks the syntax of these files as if it would be html. How can I tell NetBeans not to check theses file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each HTML validation error as a hint in the left margin of editor : if you click on it, NetBeans proposes amongst many solutions to disable validation checking. I didn't found a dedicated option in general Preferences menu to disable it otherwise.